# Data Scraping a Locally Stored HTML File - using Python

Tags: java, python, html, web-scraping

I have a big Excel file, and in each cell I have various HTML content containing comments made by a database user. The content in each cell is unique and varying in length. I need to get rid of all HTML syntax/tags so that I can upload this content to a database table.  How can I scrape this data using Python (or Java if there are no answers for Python)? Could you provide a code example?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code you've written. If you haven't tried anything yet, you might look into using the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library to parse the HTML, and then pulling the text from there.

Comment: Yeah might want to show an example of what one of the content strings looks like.

Comment: Excel Cell1: <html>The indicator lights on the control cabinet&nbsp;are to be replaced with 24Vdc&nbsp;LED's. 3 Red &amp;&nbsp;3 Green.</html>                                                                                            Excel Cell2:"<html><div>
 <span style=""FONT-SIZE: 18pt"">Close the Monthly LAD and Lanyard Work orders to show they were executed. </span></div>

Comment: I haven't written any code yet, I'm new to python, but that is the language I have to use.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, `pip install bs4`. Then you can extract the text with python like so:

```
import bs4

for cell in [
    '<html>The indicator lights on the control cabinet&nbsp;are to be replaced with 24Vdc&nbsp;LED\'s. 3 Red &amp;&nbsp;3 Green.</html>',
    '<html><div> <span style=""FONT-SIZE: 18pt"">Close the Monthly LAD and Lanyard Work orders to show they were executed. </span></div>']:
    print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(cell).text.strip())
```

Result:

```
The indicator lights on the control cabinet are to be replaced with 24Vdc LED's. 3 Red & 3 Green.
Close the Monthly LAD and Lanyard Work orders to show they were executed.
```